# Como realizar o complemento de 2 (binário)? Python

Tags: python, if, for, while

Quero realizar o complemento de 2 em um número binário que o usuário inserir e depois somar com 2 valores binários. EX:
111001 - 110001, faço o complemento de 2 no segundo número e então faço a soma desses valores, não consigo fazer nem o complemento de 2, muito menos a soma.
meu código:

```
c1=""
c2=""
print("O programa fará o complemento de 2 no valor inserido")
b =  input("Digite um número binário: ")
for i in range(len(b)):
    if(b[i] == "0"):
        c1 = c1 + "1"
    elif(b[i] == "1"):
        c1 = c1 + "0"
if(c1[-1] == "0"):
   c1[-1] = str(1)
   
tamanho = len(c1)-1
for i in range(tamanho+1):
  print(i)
  print(tamanho)
  c2 = c2 + c1[i]
print("inicio:",b)
print("c1:",c1)
print("c2:",c2)
```

Comment: Para fazer a operação de um número binário com um decimal ou outro binário você pode fazer respectivamente `n = bin(int('0101', 2) + 2)` e `n = bin(int('111001', 2) + int('10', 2))`.

Comment: mas como faço o complemento de 2? sem usar uma função?

Comment: @MarcusLoureiro, creio que seja [isso](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/efficient-method-2s-complement-binary-string/) que vc procura